# How do I add another Secure URL (HTTPs) for google wallet API?

Tags: security, ssl

I am using google Wallet API.We are using secure URL for image saving.I have added another secure URL for image saving.I am getting 400 error(invalid Resource),bad request from google wallet API.But I am not getting any error for unsecured URL(http).Secured URL which are added before,it is working.Is there any need to add another SSL certificate for secured URL?Because It was working with secured URL previously.It is showing error for new secured URL.Please give your suggestion.